# About local finiteness, is this example correct?

Tags: general-topology

Learning paracompactness and the local finite part confuses me a bit.

The local finite definition is

> A collection $\{A_i \}_i$ is locally finite if $\forall x \in X$, each $x$ has an open set that meets $A_i$ for finitely many $i$.

I can't draw it, but I am guessing a collection

1) $\{A_i\}$ that encloses $x$ in an ascending order $A_i \subset A_{i + 1}$ won't work because it fails the finite part.

2) But how can the "local" part be failed? Here is my extreme example that I came up but doesn't work.  Suppose only $\{A_i\} \subset X_1$ where $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ and $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$. But this is still local because $X$ is an open set that contains everything.

Is it even possible for the local part to ever fail?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the finite part" and "the local part"?  Local finiteness is one single condition, not a conjunction of a "finite" condition and a "local" condition.

Comment: finite part because it meets only finitely many $A_i$ for each open set. local part means I guess it meets $x$. Actually this is the part I am not quite getting. Like what is "local" here mean?

Comment: As I said, the definition doesn't _have_ two parts.  It's one single definition, and the entire concept is called being "locally finite".  If you find that confusing, you can give it a different name.  For instance, you can say a collection is "French" if each $x\in X$ has an open neighborhood that meets only finitely many sets in the collection.  Does that make you happier?

Comment: I mean I just don't understand the "local" adjective here. What is it describing?

Comment: Note that it is "locally finite" not "local finite". Further, "locally" isn't an adjective; it's actually an adverb (the adjective form is _local_, but, again, that is not what is being used), and in this case it is an adverb modifying the adjective "finite", creating the adjective phrase "locally finite". As Eric Wofsey has mentioned, "locally finite" needs to be understood as a single descriptor with a specific definition. We use the entire adjective phrase instead of a single adjective like "manxome" because there is a sense of finiteness to the definition.

Comment: Let A be all the open balls of the plane.  A is not locally finite.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a covering of the plane consisting of all the open balls which do not contain (0,0) and just one that does. The covering is finite at (0,0) as that point is in only one member of the covering, but not locally finite there as any neighbourhood of (0,0) will meet infinitely many of the other members.

Note locally finite at a point only requires *one* neighbourhood which meets only finitely many members of the covering.

Answer (score 1):

An example and a non-example (both in $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology:

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{(n, n+1), n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is locally finite. If $x$ is in some $(n, n+1)$ (so $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$) the neighbourhood $U_x = (n, n+1)$ intersects only $(n,n+1) \in \mathcal{A}$ , otherwise $x=n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and th neighbourhood $U_x = (n-\frac{1}{2}, n+\frac{1}{2})$ intersects only two members of $\mathcal{A}$, $(n-1,n)$ on its left and $(n,n+1)$ on its right. 
So for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have a neighbourhood $U_x$ that witnesses its  local finiteness .

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}): n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$. 
This family is not locally finite, because for $x=0$, *any* neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ contains some set of the form $(-r,r)$, and for $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < r$, we have that $(-r,r)$ (and thus $U_x$ as well) intersects (even contains) all $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n})$ where $n \ge N$, so infinitely many members of $\mathcal{A}$. So the condition of being locally finite fails at $x=0$ so $\mathcal{A}$ is not locally finite in $\mathbb{R}$.